# allowed values for node/entity/user reference field

Tags: 7, nodes, users, entities

Can you get allowed values for reference field?

i tried with:

```
$all_fields_info = field_info_fields();
$allowed_values= list_allowed_values($all_fields_info["field_user_ref"]);
```

but it is not working ..

Comment: An entity reference field isn't an list field, so no, it doesn't haves "allowed values" as such

Comment: How do you get the available options then?

Answer (score 1):

For an entityreference fields use:

```
$allowed_values = entityreference_get_selection_handler("field_user_ref")->getReferencableEntities();
```